# bugs program received signal sigsegv, segmentation fault

Tags: c++

When I try to run this program, it doesn't work. When I go to debugs, a message pops up
"program received signal sigsegv, segmentation fault";

```
# include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
int a[1000000]; 
cout<< a[2];
return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of data to put on the stack. You could make the array global or dynamically allocate it.

Comment: Tip: In C++ use `std::vector` when you can, *especially* for large arrays.